# Applying a CSS theme to a compiled Qt Program

Tags: qt, qt5, themes

How can I apply a CSS Qt theme (i.e style-sheet) to a compiled Qt program ? ( i.e without using the API e.g `QWidget::setStyleSheet` ).

I want to use it as a theme for a specified Qt application.

Comment: You can pass a [command line arg](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication).

Comment: @G.M. OK . But what if the target program isn't mine?

Comment: Not sure I understand your last comment.  Just invoke the application as `appname -stylesheet=<path-to-stylesheet-file>` .

Comment: @G.M. OK , got it. Is there any environment variable for this purpose ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks. You can post is as the answer if you want.